# How to link controls to Canvas sprites?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

Any input is GREATLY appreciated!

Long story short, I need to figure out how to use HTML5/CSS3 buttons to control sprite animations on my canvas. The buttons control the sprites direction and speed individually.

I have two arrays which represent the two types of sprite controls each indexed to their varying degrees(1 w/ three indexes and 1 w/ 8 indexes). What method should I go about linking the buttons to their respective "transformation" of my sprite? My sprites are tiled and indexed in the 8-index array, so traditionally transforming the image is unnecessary. I need the click of each button to change a specific array to a specific index which will then be inserted into the drawImage() and clearRect () formulas to create the animation. Each click should change only the one array and index number, leaving everything else the same. . . Am I going about it correctly to place the speed and direction values in arrays? Any ideas?

**HTML**

Div controlPanel is z-indexed above the canvas and contains all of the control buttons.

```
<div id="controlPanel">
    <div id="rightButtons">
        <div id="fast">
            <button type="button" class="speed" name="fast" value="2"></button>
        </div>       
        <div id="medium">
            <button type="button" class="speed" name="medium" value="1"></button>
        </div> 
        <div id="slow">
            <button type="button" class="speed" name="slow" value="0"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottomButtons">
        <div id="H0">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H0" value="0"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H1">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H1" value="1"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H2">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H2" value="2"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H3">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H3" value="3"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H4">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H4" value="4"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H5">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H5" value="5"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H6">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H6" value="6"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="H7">
            <button type="button" class="heading" name="H7" value="7"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**EXT. JAVASCRIPT**

```
var heading = [180,210,0,30,60,90,120,150] //x-coordinates of the sprite tile
var speed = [5,10,20];


document.getElementById("plane").onload=function(){
var canvasTwo = document.getElementById("canvasTwo");
var cxt = canvasTwo.getContext("2d");
var plane = document.getElementById("plane");
animatePlane();
}

    function animatePlane(){

    setInterval(drawPlane,200);
    }

    var plane = document.getElementById("plane");   
    var dy = speed;
    var dx = s;
    var x = 400;
    var y = 475;

    function drawPlane(){

        y = y+dy; 
        x = x + dx;
        cxt.save();
        cxt.clearRect(x-dx,y-dy,30,30);
        cxt.drawImage(plane,heading,0,30,30,x,y,30,30);
        cxt.restore();
    }

        //This is where dx and dy get alittle funky. The value of dx and dy depend on the heading. Quite frankly I don't know where to place this block of code.

        //to determine the value of dx
        if (heading[]= 0){
            dx= speed[];
            dy= 0;
        }
        if (heading[]= 30){
            dx= speed[];
            dy= speed[]*-1;
        }
        if (heading[]= 60){
            dx= 0;
            dy= speed[]*-1;
        }
        if (heading[]= 90){
            dx= speed[]*-1;
            dy= speed[]*-1;
        }
        if (heading[]= 150){
            dx= speed[]*-1;
            dy= speed[];
        }
        if (heading[]= 180){
            dx= 0;
            dy= speed[];
        } 
        if (heading[]= 210){
            dx= speed[];
            dy= speed[];
        }
```

Comment: Can you post a example of the code you have now? Basically what you want to do is have your buttons edit some data related to the drawn items, then re-draw the items based on that edited data. From what I can see, you're thinking in the right direction.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks for responding. I've updated my post with the code included. Should I be using <button> or <input> for my controls? Also, there will be several sprites on the screen at any given time. I haven't quite figured out how to do that yet but it might be helpful for you to know. MANY MANY MANY thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could just comment on the post, but here are a few things.

Your use of button is perfectly fine, but the `type="button"` is redundant, so you can take that out if you see fit.

Also this:

```
var speed = [5,10,20];
...
var dy = speed;
var dx = s;
var x = 400;
var y = 475;
...
y = y+dy;
...
if (heading[]= 0){
   dx= speed[];
...
```

confuses me. `dy = speed` means `dy` is an array, but you are trying to add it with an integer, which produces a string;

`dx = s` but you haven't posted `s`'s initialization in the code (though it could be somewhere else).

When referring to an index in an array (in javascript) you MUST include a positive integer or 0 within the brackets. `heading[]` throws an error. I guess that could just be empty for the time being, but you will fill it later.

When doing equality comparisons in javascript, you use `==`. `=` is an  asignment. So, `if(myVar=0)` will assign 0 to myVar, not compare it to 0.

Having all the speeds and headings within arrays is a good way to go. In order to utilize them, you will have to establish some variables to contain which index is being used. Such as

```
var i_heading = 0; // the heading array's index
var i_speed = 0; // the speed array's index
```

You could then use the `onclick=` event for the buttons, with another function.

```
<div id="fast">
   <button class="speed" name="fast" value="2" onclick="setSpeedIndex(this.value)"></button>
</div>

<script>
   function setSpeedIndex(newSpeedIndex){
       i_speed = newSpeedIndex;
   }
   ...
   if (heading[i_heading]= 0){
       dx= speed[i_speed];
       dy= 0;
   }
</script>
```

And you can extend that for the heading as well.

FINALLY. Putting multiple sprites on the screen can be done many ways, but you will need an array containing all of your planes. Essentially you will need to make a plane "class." That can be a `function Plane()` or just a data structure. You can grab each plane's information by looping through the array and draw from within the loop. Or, if you use the function as a plane class, you can have the planes draw themselves.

**function class**

```
var planes = []; // array of planes
...
function Plane(x, y, s, h){ // plane function, a.k.a. class
    this.x = x;
    ...
    this.drawMyself = function(){ // function to draw itself
        this.y = this.y+this.dy;
        ... // the rest of the drawing function
    }
}
...
planes.add(new Plane(0,0,0,0)); // adding a plane
...
for ( var i in planes){ // drawing all the planes
    var p = planes[i];
    p.drawMyself(); 
}
```

**data structure**

```
var planes = []; // array of planes
...
planes.add({ // adding the data structure
    x: 0,
    ...
});
...
for ( var i in planes){ // drawing all the planes
    var p = planes[i];
    p.y = p.y+p.dy;
    ... // the rest of the drawing function
}
```

If you need any more help in javascript, [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) is a great source.

Comment: You are an absolute ROCKSTAR!!! Thank you sooo much for the help. As you can see my code is alittle rough around the edges, to say the least. I only just started teaching myself the language maybe three weeks ago. So ALL of your help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Also, there is an online (and free) university called Udacity. They have an HTML5 Javascript game making class going on right now that you might be interested in looking at.